# Insert Image(From Phone's Image Gallery) In Edittext Inline With Text

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-imageview, android-image

I'm trying to insert an image inline with text inside an EditText widget on Android.  When I go to click on the "Take" button, I select the "Choose From Gallery" in the dialog.  When I choose an image from the Android Image Gallery the "string" Toast message popups however the image doesn't get inserted into the EditText inline with the text.  Here is the source code that I'm using:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.style.ImageSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.kh9275.stuff.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText et;
Button keyboard, camera, take;
LinearLayout cameraLayout;
GridLayout grid;
SharedPreferences prefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
static int index;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    keyboard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keyboard);
    camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera);
    take = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take);
    cameraLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cameraLayout);
    cameraLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    grid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("stuff", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    index = prefs.getInt("index", 1);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + index, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    editor = prefs.edit();
    int i = 1;
    while (i < index) {
        String s = "" + i;
        String path = getPath(this, Uri.parse(prefs.getString(s, "string")));

        final ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        Bitmap b = null;
        try {
            b = getThumbnail(getContentResolver(), path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        iv.setImageBitmap(b);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);
        iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addImageBetweentext(iv.getDrawable());
            }
        });
        grid.addView(iv);
        i++;
    }

    keyboard.setOnClickListener(this);
    camera.setOnClickListener(this);
    take.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        //camera
        String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null,
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

        cursor.close();

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
        int i = prefs.getInt("index", 1);
        i++;
        editor.putInt("index", i);
        editor.putString("" + i, uri.toString());
        editor.commit();
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(uri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Bitmap b = null;
        try {
            b = getThumbnail(getContentResolver(), path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);
        iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        iv.setImageBitmap(b);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addImageBetweentext(iv.getDrawable());
            }
        });
        grid.addView(iv);

    }
    if (requestCode == 2) {
        //from gallery
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        int i = prefs.getInt("index", 1);
        i++;
        editor.putInt("index", i);
        editor.putString("" + i, uri.toString());
        editor.commit();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), prefs.getString("1", "string"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        Bitmap b = null;
        try {
            b = getThumbnail(getContentResolver(), getPath(getApplicationContext(), uri));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);
        iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        iv.setImageBitmap(b);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addImageBetweentext(iv.getDrawable());
            }
        });
        grid.addView(iv);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.keyboard:
            cameraLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            et.hasFocus();
            if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(view, 0);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.camera:
            cameraLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            et.clearFocus();
            if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.take:
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Insert a photo");
            alert.setNegativeButton("Take from camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
                }
            });
            alert.setPositiveButton("Choose from gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
                    gallery.setType("image/*");
                    gallery.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery, "Select an image"), 2);
                }
            });
            alert.show();
            break;
    }
}

public static Bitmap getThumbnail(ContentResolver cr, String path) throws Exception {

    Cursor ca = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID}, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{path}, null);
    if (ca != null && ca.moveToFirst()) {
        int id = ca.getInt(ca.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
        ca.close();
        return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
    }

    ca.close();
    return null;

}

private void addImageBetweentext(Drawable drawable) {
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

    int selectionCursor = et.getSelectionStart();
    et.getText().insert(selectionCursor, ".");
    selectionCursor = et.getSelectionStart();

    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(et.getText());
    builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(drawable), selectionCursor - ".".length(), selectionCursor,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    et.setText(builder);
    et.setSelection(selectionCursor);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
}
```

Here is the XML layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="keyboard" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Camera" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/cameraLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/take"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Take" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnCount="5">


        </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What code do I need to accomplish this?

Comment: So `private void addImageBetweentext(Drawable drawable)` does not work as you expected it to work. Why post all that other code? The rest is irrelevant. You should have narrowed down the problem first.

Comment: @user268397 did you get any responses on this question or were you able to solve it yourself?